# Store a python collections.Counter as PickleProperty in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, counter

I am able to store a collections.Counter into the app engine data store, however when I retrieve it and try to parse it, I get the following error:

```
for word in counter:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

If I just print the output, it shows:

```
Counter({'a': 25, 'b': 12, 'c': 10, 'd': 9})
```

Now if I initialize a dictionary with the same values, I store it the same way as the counter, I can retrieve it and parse it without any problem:

```
counter = Counter()
counter = {'a': 25, 'b': 12, 'c': 10, 'd': 9};
...
#Store in app engine datastore and retrieve as "values"
...
for letter in values:
    self.response.write(letter + ":" + str(values[letter]) + "<br>")
```

Output:
a:25
c:10
b:12
d:9

Does this mean you cannot store a Counter but should better transform as a Dictionary before storing it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the code that retrieves the counter? If you are able to print it you did something else wrong, and the `counter` name in your code is set to `None`.

Comment: As stupid as it seems, I can't reproduce the error... My guess is that I had a mess in the datastore. Clearing it most likely fixed the problem. Thanks Martijn!